# Remix Won't Allow me to deploy my contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

Remix is telling me "Currently you have no contract instances to interact with." But that's because Remix Won't Allow me to deploy my contract. Please Help I'm new to this[Picture of my remix smart contract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcUPn.png)

Comment: Hit the `deploy` button, then you see green tick in console on bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

You have not compiled your smart contract. You need to first compile your smart contract only then you can deploy your smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

I was using REMIX. I just refreshed the website and it worked for me.